# Is the sentence a noun phrase/clause

Tags: phrases, clauses

Is the part in bracket

> He  is not sure (where to start a new business)

A noun clause or noun phrase

Comment: It is a subordinate interrogative functioning as complement of the adjective "sure".

Answer (score 0):

The answer is noun phrase because it cannot be a clause since it does not have a finite verb.
A ohra is a group of words that does not make sense and does not tell either it is past, present or future. So in order for it to be a clause, a finite verb should be present. So it is a noun phrase

Comment: Isn't to start a verb?

Comment: "Start" is a verb, but it's non-finite @Talha. But Haleema, a clause can be finite or non-finite. In this case, the infinival clause is a non-finite clause. "Where to start a new business" is just an infinitival interrogative clause. It's no different from "where I should start a new business".

Comment: @user178049 in that case it should be a noun clause i guess

Comment: @Talha Nope. A noun clause is a confusing term. Huddleston & Pullum (2002) analyze this as a subordinate interrogative clause.

Comment: @user178049 thanks for the explaination. Suppose if you have to choose between noun clause/phrase or adverb clause/phrase which one would be most suitable